# Fabric-sdk-go How to create the client context using msp CAclient

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i am trying to use the hyperledger go sdk by importing on 
 of the module

`https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp` .

I want to create the CA client instance by using hyperledger fabric go-sdk, which module do i need to import and how to do it, could anyone please suggest?

I am using below cmd to generate the fabric server CA client config file.

```
./bin/fabric-ca-client enroll admin:adminpws localhost:7054
```

Below is the code, which create the fabric sdk context, using the fabric-ca-client.yaml file which is generated by using the above cmd. if i am doing anything wrong let me know.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net"
"os"
"path/filepath"
"strings"

clientmsp "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/common/providers/core"
mspid "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/common/providers/msp"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/core/config"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/core/cryptosuite"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/msp"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/msp/test/mockmsp"
 )

var (DefaultHome = os.ExpandEnv("$PWD/CONFIG"))
var caServerURL string
var caServer = &mockmsp.MockFabricCAServer{}
const (
caServerURLListen = "http://localhost:7054"
configFile        = "fabric-ca-server-config.yaml"
)

type nwConfig struct {
CertificateAuthorities map[string]msp.CAConfig
 }

type clientFixture struct {
cryptoSuiteConfig core.CryptoSuiteConfig
identityConfig    mspid.IdentityConfig
}

func main() {

// Initiate the sdk using the config file
client := clientFixture{}
sdk := client.setup()
//create the CA instance
c, err := clientmsp.New(sdk.Context())
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("failed to create msp client", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println("New client instance created", c)
}

func (f *clientFixture) setup() *fabsdk.FabricSDK {
var lis net.Listener
var err error
if !caServer.Running() {
    lis, err = net.Listen("tcp", strings.TrimPrefix(caServerURLListen, 
  "http://"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error starting CA Server %s", err))
    }

    caServerURL = "http://" + lis.Addr().String()
}

configPath := filepath.Join(DefaultHome, configFile)
backend, err := config.FromFile(configPath)()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
configProvider := func() ([]core.ConfigBackend, error) {
    return backend, nil
}

// Instantiate the SDK
sdk, err := fabsdk.New(configProvider)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

configBackend, err := sdk.Config()
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to get config: %s", err))
}

f.cryptoSuiteConfig = cryptosuite.ConfigFromBackend(configBackend)
f.identityConfig, _ = msp.ConfigFromBackend(configBackend)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
ctxProvider := sdk.Context()
ctx, err := ctxProvider()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

// Start Http Server if it's not running
if !caServer.Running() {
    caServer.Start(lis, ctx.CryptoSuite())
}
return sdk
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import mspclient

```
mspclient "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp"
          "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk"

    mspClient, err := mspclient.New(
        *fabsdk.FabricSDK.Context(),
        mspclient.WithOrg(OrgName),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return mspClient, errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to create MSP client")
    }
```

After that you can use below services

```
    err = mspClient.Enroll("Admin@org1",
        msp.WithSecret("Admin@org1"),
        msp.WithProfile("tls"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to register identity")
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replay, *fabsdk.FabricSDK.Context(), which is client provider right, To create the client provider, we need to use the fabric-ca-client-config.yaml to create the FabricSDK.Context() am i right or i need to use different configuration file.please i am confused here.

Comment: I have updated my answer fabsdk, you need to import that package

Comment: thank you, do i need to load any configuration file, before i start a mspclient.New(
        *fabsdk.FabricSDK.Context(),
        mspclient.WithOrg(OrgName),
    )

Comment: Hi @fama I appreciate your interest in hyperledger fabric and your hard work really impressive. Check this tutorial for gosdk https://chainhero.io/2018/03/tutorial-build-blockchain-app-2/

Comment: thank you @narendranth, i check that chainhero demo,In demo,crypto-config is already generated and they use the config.yaml file which use to generate configtx. But what i want is to connect Fabric-sdk-go with farbic CA and using Fabric sdk api to register and enroll the admin,user create keypair. I observer here, fabric-ca-server-config file generated by CA Server is completed different from which everyone use for demo example crypto-config.yaml file and configtx.yaml file. I am stuck in using proper config file to create fabric sdk context to connect with fabric CA.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is, first, i ll run fabric-ca server which create fabric-server-config.yaml with sqllite db. I want to create RPC wrapper on top fabric-sdk-go. So 2 layers application rpc wrapper underneath fabric-sdk-go, UI will call RPC register method to register has admin, through rpc its call fabric-sdk-go method register api from api it will hit the fabric CA server to register. If i want to run my RPC methods, I need to initiate the fabric CA client and fabric-sdk-go in myapp(RPC register methods) where i am exposing rpc method.